# Special characters (utf-8) in PHP contact message

Tags: php, utf-8, contact-form

I have a contact form. When i receive a message, i can not read it normally because the special characters are shown bizarrly.

I saved my file in utf-8 without BOM, I red and tried a lot of variations about this subject but I could not find the right answer for myself.

The contact form in my html :

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 


<form id="contactform" action="processform.php" method="post" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <div class="form-label label-name">Nom</div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <div class="form-label label-postcode">Code Postal</div>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" />
    <div class="form-label label-email">E-mail</div>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <div class="form-label label-subject">Sujet</div>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
    <div class="form-label label-message">Message</div>
    <textarea rows="4" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="send" name="button" value="Envoyer" />           
</form>
```

My processform.php file (saved in UTF-8 without BOM) has the following codes :

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['verif']) == false) {
  // the code was incorrect
  // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

  // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
  echo "Le code de s&eacute;curit&eacute; indiqu&eacute; est incorrect.<br />";
  echo "Rafra&icirc;chissez la page et essayez &agrave; nouveau svp.";
  exit;
}

// Clean up the input values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

  $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Test input values for errors
$errors = array();
if(strlen($name) < 3) {
  if(!$name) {
    $errors[] = "Entrez votre nom svp.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Au moins 3 caractères sont requis pour un nom.";
  }
}
if(!$email) {
  $errors[] = "Entrez votre email svp.";
} else if(!validEmail($email)) {
  $errors[] = "Veuillez fournir une adresse valide svp.";
}
if(strlen($message) < 20) {
  if(!$message) {
    $errors[] = "Entrez un message svp.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Au moins 20 caractères sont requis pour un message.";
  }
}

if($errors) {
  // Output errors and die with a failure message
  $errortext = "";
  foreach($errors as $error) {
    $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
  }
  die("<span class='failure'>Les erreurs suivantes sont survenues :<ul>". $errortext ."</ul></span>");
}

// Remplacement de certains caractères spéciaux
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// Send the email
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$message = "
From: $name 
Email: $email 
Subject: $subject
Message: $message";
$headers = "Message from West Hungary website";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Die with a success message
die("<span class='success'>Votre message a &eacute;t&eacute; envoy&eacute; avec succ&egrave;s !</span>");

// A function that checks to see if
// an email is valid
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}

?>
```

Comment: A side note: since you're using UTF-8, consider using php multibyte functions [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). For example: replace `strlen('è')` with `mb_strlen('è')`, the `strlen` will return 2 while `mb_strlen` will return 1. Other mb functions are: `strrpos` to `mb_strrpos`, `substr` to `mb_substr`

Comment: Thank you ! I added `_mb` to all `strlen`, `strrpos` and `substr` but i get still strange characters... i went to the link you gave me, it's completely not understandable for me, howeveri found something which can be interesting maybe : how can i add this to my processform file concerning the message body : `mixed mb_strlen ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`... the only part where i must encoding, it is the body of my message what i receive by mail...

Comment: You need to pass the encoding for each of these `mb_` function, for example: `mb_strlen('è', 'UTF-8');` or call `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` in the beginning of the file so you don't need to pass 'UTF-8' for the `mb_` functions. For the mail to work correctly, pass `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"` in the $header

Comment: IgorLaszlo Have you tried to replace the PHP function mail() with SwiftMailer library? I have used on projects in multiple languages without any problem.

It has a very complete documentation you can check here: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/overview.html

I hope this help.

Comment: @evilReiko - please write an answer, you will get the bounty ! it is your comment which drove me to the solution ! It works only with the `mb-strlen` and the `$headers "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"` together !
The final codes which work look like :

**`mb_strlen('è', 'UTF-8');
mb_strlen('é', 'UTF-8');
mb_strlen('ë', 'UTF-8');
etc.
// Send the email
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$message = "
Message from West Hungary website
<br />
From: $name 
<br />
Email: $email
<br /> 
Subject: $subject
<br />
Message: $message";`**

Comment: @evilReiko - i forgot to say that hopefully you do not sleep yet because the bounty is ending in 20 hours by the system ! :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @TobyAllen - you are right, i guess i deleted my question when i edited my text for adding the php code or the bounty text... i readded now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using UTF-8, consider using php multibyte functions link `mb_`*. For example:

```
echo strlen('è'); // output 2
echo mb_strlen('è', 'UTF-8'); // output 1
```

Other mb_* functions you might be interested in:

`strrpos()` to `mb_strrpos()`

`substr()` to `mb_substr()`

For full list of multibyte functions, look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

If you don't want to pass 'UTF-8' in every mb_ function, call `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` in the beginning of your script.

For the `mail()` function to work properly with UTF-8, pass the following in the header:

```
$header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now the message bodies show normal characters... i got a lot of good answers but they did not work alone... yours is complete.

Comment: No one knows how UTF-8 works until you get into the infamous "UTF-8 hell" !

Answer (score 4):

try to add this line to headers,

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
```

Comment: Also you can use `utf8_encode()`.

    `$message = utf8_encode( 
    "De: $name
    E-mail: $email
    Code Postal: $value
    Subject: $subject
    Message: $message");`

Comment: @Vic Why do you want to utf8_encode a string which is already UTF-8 encoded?!

Comment: here we are encoding the data that is sent in the email

Comment: @Chandu : how can i add my own `$headers = 'Message via le formulaire de contact du site web Volumes Et Surfaces\r\n';` line ? My line is first or the last ? Do i have to put a dat there : `$headers .=` for mine ?

Comment: @IgorLaszlo You can concatenate with the dot separator (.) Example: $headers .= "Message via le formulaire de contact du site web Volumes Et Surfaces\r\n'; after the existing header variable.

Comment: yes you can add your own headers, unitl the above two lines are included,before you send the email

Comment: Nor the headers change, neither the utf8_encode of the message change works... Non of them...

Answer (score 1):

1-Make sure to have this in your HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

2-Then add this to the beginning of your PHP script:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Example of the first two steps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
      <title>PHP Special Characters</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
         $header= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
         $header.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
         echo "àè";
      ?>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Alternatively to the step 2, you could add this to your .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

If none of the above works, use this in your PHP code (make sure to set correct location):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA.utf-8');
```

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it did not help either... the only thing i did not try is to add the line to the .htaccess...

Comment: Try the .htaccess. Also, I noticed you have two meta tags in your html, you only need the second one. Furthermore, are you using that form in a .html? It should be a .php, unless they're on the same .php page. That could be preventing it from being sent.

Comment: I have an html (my index.html) where the form is installed, then i have my processform.php where i have html codes and php codes...

Comment: i do not have any .htaccess file in my folder... if i create one, is your code enough in it ?

Comment: Yes. that is all you'll need, it doesn't need other necessary code for these purposes.

Comment: I added the .htaccess file to the folder and i could not be connected on my whole website...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to transform the text you want to display with this PHP function.
It take an UTF8 encoded string as argument and return the string converted in ISO-8859-1 characters

```
utf8_decode($your_text)
```

Comment: Thanks but you did not understand my question... i do not have problem with my own texts, the message body does not appear well what my visitors send via my contact form... i can not read my messages correctly in the mail i receive...